# Authenticate Azure API Management with OAuth2 using Azure AD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I am trying to secure APIM APIs using OAuth2 via AzureAD by reading the article: [Protect a web API backend in Azure API Management by using OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)

AzureAPIM - OAuth2

- Authorization endpoint URL (v1): [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/authorize)
- Token endpoint URL (v1): [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/token)
- Client ID: client-app id
- Redirect URI: (deprecated portal): https://xxx-api.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/auth1/console/oauth2/authorizationcode/callback

AzureAD - backend-app:

- scope: Files.All

AzureAD - client-app:

- secret key: xxx
- Redirect url: ONLY WORK with deprecated portal in APIM (https://xxx-api.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/auth1/console/oauth2/authorizationcode/callback)

For Demo Conference API, Add Validate JWT policy to Inbound processing where `3a0cf09b-` is tenant id and `b7c31179-` is backend-app application id:
[image]

In Developer portal, the authentication to AzureAD is successful with a return token:
[image]

However the authorization is failed with calling the API:
[image]

Inspecting the received token in jwt.io, I found that the `"aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"` is not backend-app application id:

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/3a0cf09b-xxx/",
  "app_displayname": "client-app",
  "appid": "05a245fb-xxx",
  "scp": "Files.Read User.Read profile openid email",
  "tenant_region_scope": "OC",
  "tid": "3a0cf09b-2952-4673-9ace-0e1bf69ee23a",
  "unique_name": "user1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
}
```

API Test HTTP response trace shows the error on validate-jwt:

```
validate-jwt (-0.138 ms)
{
    "message": "JWT Validation Failed: Claim value mismatch: aud=b7c31179-xxx.."
}
```

Replacing `aud` by the value in the token `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` or removing the `required-claims` in the `validate-jwt` policy to get it working.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you choose v1 endpoint of OAuth2 authorization but not v2 endpoint, so the value of `aud` in access token should be like `b7c31179-xxxx....` but not `api://b7c31179-xxxx....`. So there are no mistakes in your steps of get access token.

According to some test in my side, the cause of this problem is you did not specify a parameter `resource` with the value of the backend-app application id when you configure OAuth2.0 in your APIM. The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#enable-oauth-20-user-authorization-in-the-developer-console) you refer to also mentions this (I test with not specify this parameter, it shows same problem with yours)
[image]

So to solve this problem, please go to your APIM and click "**OAuth 2.0**" tab, edit the item you created. Add a parameter `resource` with value of the backend-app application id.
[image]

**Note**: When you add the parameter `resource` and click "Save" button, please open the item again and check if the "**Client secret**" box is empty. When I test in my side, the "**Client secret**" box shows empty after add parameter `resource`, it may be a bug on that page. If "**Client secret**" is empty, it might show error message like `The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'` when you get the access token in Developer portal.

Comment: Thanks Hury. Forgot to add resource={backend app id} in APIM OAuth2 (v1)

Answer (score 4):

From your error report, it is indeed a 401 error, that is, your `aud` does not match the api you want to call, I use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to do a simple demonstration for you:

First expose the api of the back-end application and add the client application.

[image]

Next,under 'API permissions', give your front-end application access to your backend api:

- Under 'API permissions' click on 'Add permission', then click on the 'My APIs' tab.
- Find your backend application and select the appropriate scope.
- Click 'Add permissions'.
- Grant admin consent for your APIs.

[image]

Get token:

[image]

Parse the token：

[image]

Comment: Thanks Carl. Confirmed it is working with v2. 

For testing I manually got the `authorization code` from https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize then `access token` from https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token via Postman.